# Connecting Android with Raspberry PI

Tags: android, usb, raspberry-pi

The requirement is to use android phone APP to write the data on the Raspberry PI device.

Connection between PI and android will be done using the USB cable.

Data can be written in the form of a file on the filesystem of PI or can be transmitted as a String to some process running on the PI. Later is preferable.

Has somebody done that or has pointers for me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send any string from Android to PI over USB first read about the AOA(Android open accessory) Protocol. This protocol is used communication over USB.
for this type of implementation you have to use this permission into your manifest

More information about this go [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)

you can use the the MQTT protocol for send any string from Android smart phone to PI by using IP and Port no.